# Delete files, directories and buckets in amazon s3 java

Tags: java, amazon-web-services

I'm wondering how to do this. I looked at the sdk documentation and have some examples, but am confused how the syntax generally goes.

If I want to delete a file, I assume I use `deleteObject(path, key)`. However, what is the "key"?

Also how do you delete a directory? I can't seem to find a method for doing that.

Comment: did you find the solution to delete a folder??

Comment: Only an empty directory can be deleted. So, first delete the contents and then delete the directory using s3Client.deleteObject(bucket name, folderName).

Comment: [Refer this](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/message.jspa?messageID=225866)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

A "key" in S3 is similar to a file path:

```
http://bucket.s3.amazonaws.com/some/path/to/use
```

... is in a bucket named `bucket` and has a key of `some/path/to/use`.

It's not actually a path though, because there are no folders. The S3 key is just the file name for a file in one big directory (the entire bucket). S3 keys can contain `/`, but it has no special meaning unless you set the [`delimiter` argument with listing a bucket](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/v2-RESTBucketGET.html).

In other words, having an object named `some/object` doesn't tell you anything about the object `some` (it might or might not exist -- the two objects are not related).

However, you can request keys with a specific prefix, so I could say "give me all keys starting with `some/path/to/` and it will return `some/path/to/use`. It looks like "listing a directory", but it's really just asking for files that start with a specific string of characters.

I could just as easily name things like this:

```
somepathtousea
somepathtouseb
```

And say "give me everything starting with `somepathtouse`" (and it would say `somepathtousea` and `somepathtouseb`).

Note: S3 URL's come in [several forms](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amazon_S3#Design):

> ```
> http://s3.amazonaws.com/bucket/key
> http://bucket.s3.amazonaws.com/key
> http://bucket/key (where bucket is a DNS CNAME record pointing to bucket.s3.amazonaws.com)
> ```

EDIT:

I looked at [the JavaDocs](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/s3/AmazonS3Client.html) and this is the function signature I see (for `AmazonS3Client`):

```
public void deleteObject(java.lang.String bucketName,
                         java.lang.String key)
                  throws AmazonClientException,
                         AmazonServiceException
```

EDIT again:

Folders do kind-of exist now, as zero-length objects with a content-type of `application/x-directory` and a key ending in `/`:

```
$ AWS_PROFILE=prod aws s3api head-object --bucket example-bucket --key example-directory/
{
    "AcceptRanges": "bytes",
    "LastModified": "Mon, 29 Apr 2019 14:59:36 GMT",
    "ContentLength": 0,
    "ETag": "\"d41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427e\"",
    "ContentType": "application/x-directory",
    "ServerSideEncryption": "AES256",
    "Metadata": {}
}
```

This is still just convention and there's nothing stopping you from having files ending `/` or files inside of "folders" that don't exist.

Comment: so really the syntax should be `deleteObject(bucketName, path)`?

Comment: @cfarm54 - Except a key isn't a path. They key-bucket relationship is more like.. the key is a file name (which may contain `/`) and the bucket is one big folder.

Comment: Thanks, and how would you delete the directory and bucket?

Comment: @cfarm54 - What I'm trying to get across is that there are no directories. You can't delete one because they don't exist. To delete a bucket, I suspect you would call `AmazonS3Client.deleteBucket(String bucketname)`

Comment: but lets say that your file structure was /mybucket/dir1/dir2 and in dir2 you have a set of files. Right now you covered how to delete individual files, but what if i want to delete dir2 or dir1? and then the next question is how do i delete the whole `mybucket`?

Comment: @cfarm54 - Look at the [documentation for AmazonS3Client](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/s3/AmazonS3Client.html). `deleteBucket(String bucketName)` deletes an entire bucket. [S3 has no method to delete keys with a common prefix](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3178685/how-to-delete-lot-of-objects-named-with-common-prefix-from-s3-bucket). You'll have to list them (`listObjects(String bucketName, String prefix)`) and then delete them individually.

Comment: @BrendanLong if there are only object keys and no directories, how is it that the CLI has recursive option, and that the .Net SDK allows to delete directories? https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdkfornet/v3/apidocs/items/S3/MS3DirectoryInfoDeleteBoolean.html

Comment: S3 lets you request files by prefix, which is kind of like listing a directory, but these are two differences: directories don't exist, so you don't need to create them, and `/` isn't special: you can do something like `aws s3 ls my-bucket/some-prefix` and it will find files like `my-bucket/some-prefix.json`

Comment: If you do `aws s3 ls my-bucket/some-dir/` you will find files like `my-bucket/some-dir/file1.txt` but you will not see `my-bucket/some-dir/some-sub-dir/file2.txt`, unless you use the `--recursive` option. So `/` is special for the CLI. Not for S3 as an object store, but for the AWS CLI. And did you look at the .Net SDK? It has a `S3DirectoryInfo` class. The Java SDK seems more limited. It looks like a missing a feature.

Comment: Ah I see, if you set `delimiter` to `/`, ListBucket will sort-of treat `/`'s in keys as directory separators: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/v2-RESTBucketGET.html I assume awscli sets this by default.

Answer (score 49):

This snippet of code works for me.  folderPath is something like "topDir/secondDir/"

```
void deleteObjectsInFolder(String bucketName, String folderPath) {
   for (S3ObjectSummary file : s3.listObjects(bucketName, folderPath).getObjectSummaries()){
      s3.deleteObject(bucketName, file.getKey());
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you provide more information on why this code doesn't work for you?  I copied it from my running code.

Comment: careful that getObjectSummaries can return a truncated list !

Comment: Anyone have an idea how to do this with V2?

Answer (score 8):

You might want to take a look at this [example](http://jets3t.s3.amazonaws.com/toolkit/code-samples.html#deleting) for a quick reference on how you can delete objects from S3.

The syntax for `delete` is actually
`deleteObject( bucketName, key )`
where bucketName is the bucket in which you have placed your files and key is name of the file you want to delete within the bucket.

Think of a bucket as your hard disk drive like C:\ , D:\ etc. And key as the absolute pathname of a file you want to delete.

Answer (score 6):

/*Here is solution that works for me. Here Bucket_Name is my bucket name on S3, and key is the path under Bucket_Name. So, if absolute path on S3 is:

s3://my_bucket/Path/to/my/folder

then, the code below should work. */

---

```
    String Bucket_Name = "my_bucket";
    String key = "Path/to/my/folder";   
    ObjectListing objects = s3Client.listObjects(BUCKET_NAME, key);
        for (S3ObjectSummary objectSummary : objects.getObjectSummaries()) 
            {
            s3Client.deleteObject(BUCKET_NAME, objectSummary.getKey());
            }
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. You haven't addressed the question of "what is the key". You are supplying code but it needs some explanation to make it higher value for other users with questions.

Comment: @ShawnMehan: Thanks for your feedback, I will update my answer.

Answer (score 4):

As question is asking about Deleting files, directories and buckets in amazon S3 java, I would like to offer code for deleting a non-empty S3 bucket ([AWS Reference](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/delete-or-empty-bucket.html#delete-bucket-awssdks)):

```
 public void deleteBucket(final String bucketName) {

        final AmazonS3 s3 = AmazonS3ClientBuilder.defaultClient();

        try {
            ObjectListing objectListing = s3.listObjects(bucketName);
            while (true) {
                for (Iterator<?> iterator = objectListing.getObjectSummaries().iterator(); iterator.hasNext(); ) {
                    S3ObjectSummary summary = (S3ObjectSummary) iterator.next();
                    s3.deleteObject(bucketName, summary.getKey());
                }

                if (objectListing.isTruncated()) {
                    objectListing = s3.listNextBatchOfObjects(objectListing);
                } else {
                    break;
                }
            }

            VersionListing versionListing = s3.listVersions(new ListVersionsRequest().withBucketName(bucketName));
            while (true) {
                for (Iterator<?> iterator = versionListing.getVersionSummaries().iterator(); iterator.hasNext(); ) {
                    S3VersionSummary vs = (S3VersionSummary) iterator.next();
                    s3.deleteVersion(bucketName, vs.getKey(), vs.getVersionId());
                }

                if (versionListing.isTruncated()) {
                    versionListing = s3.listNextBatchOfVersions(versionListing);
                } else {
                    break;
                }
            }

            s3.deleteBucket(bucketName);
        } catch (AmazonServiceException e) {
            System.err.println(e.getErrorMessage());
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

This line of code works in my case where the `keyName` is the file name:

```
s3Client.deleteObject(new DeleteObjectRequest(bucketName, keyName));
```

Answer (score 2):

Works for me, beware of truncation!

```
    long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
    long totalSize = 0;
    int totalItems = 0;

    String key ="path/to/folder/"
    String bucket = "my-bucket"

    final ListObjectsRequest listObjectsRequest = new ListObjectsRequest().withBucketName(bucketName).withPrefix(key);

    ObjectListing objects = s3.listObjects(listObjectsRequest);
    do {
        for (S3ObjectSummary objectSummary : objects.getObjectSummaries()) {
            totalSize += objectSummary.getSize();
            totalItems++;
            s3.deleteObject(bucketName, objectSummary.getKey());
        }
        objects = s3.listNextBatchOfObjects(objects);
    } while (objects.isTruncated());

    long stop = System.currentTimeMillis();

    LOG.trace("User {} had {} items with {} Kb, took {} ms to delete", user.getName(), totalItems, totalSize / 1024, stop
            - start);
```

Comment: Have you tested this code? Cause I would say that in case of 'truncation' this code will not delete the last batch of files read by the `listNextBatchOfObjects`. Another thing is that I'm wondering if Amazon will properly handle listing objects in batches while they are being deleted in the same time?

Comment: As mentioned by @MJar, this code is dangerous and will not work as intended.

Comment: You need to assign the new value after the isTruncated. Something like this :
```} while (objects.isTruncated() && (objects = s3.listNextBatchOfObjects(objects)) != null);```

Answer (score 2):

The ListObjectsV2Result worked for me. Try once.

```
private void deleteObjectsInFolder() {
    try {
        ListObjectsV2Result result;
        do {
            String folderPath =   " ";



            result = s3.listObjectsV2(Constants.BUCKET_NAME, folderPath);

            Log.e("count:", result.getKeyCount() + "");

            if (result.getKeyCount() != 0) {

                for (S3ObjectSummary objectSummary :
                        result.getObjectSummaries()) {
                    s3.deleteObject(Constants.BUCKET_NAME, objectSummary.getKey());
                }

            }


            System.out.println("Next Continuation Token : " + result.getNextContinuationToken());
        } while (result.isTruncated() == true);

    } catch (AmazonServiceException ase) {
        System.out.println("Caught an AmazonServiceException, " +
                "which means your request made it " +
                "to Amazon S3, but was rejected with an error response " +
                "for some reason.");
        System.out.println("Error Message:    " + ase.getMessage());
        System.out.println("HTTP Status Code: " + ase.getStatusCode());
        System.out.println("AWS Error Code:   " + ase.getErrorCode());
        System.out.println("Error Type:       " + ase.getErrorType());
        System.out.println("Request ID:       " + ase.getRequestId());
    } catch (AmazonClientException ace) {
        System.out.println("Caught an AmazonClientException, " +
                "which means the client encountered " +
                "an internal error while trying to communicate" +
                " with S3, " +
                "such as not being able to access the network.");
        System.out.println("Error Message: " + ace.getMessage());
    }
}
```

Comment: Not efficient as will send calls to S3 for each of the folder delete, better to use `DeleteObjectsRequest` and then delete

Answer (score 2):

Deleting a list of objects from S3 bucket by bulks:

```
public void deleteObjects(String bucketName, List<String> keys) {

    List<KeyVersion> bulk = new ArrayList<>();
    for (int i = 0; i < keys.size(); i++) {
        bulk.add(new KeyVersion(keys.get(i)));
        if (i % 100 == 0) {
            try {
                s3Client.deleteObjects(new DeleteObjectsRequest(bucketName).withKeys(bulk));
            } catch (Exception e) {
                System.err.println(e.getErrorMessage());
            }
            bulk.clear();
        }
    }
    if (bulk.size() > 0) {
        try {
            s3Client.deleteObjects(new DeleteObjectsRequest(bucketName).withKeys(bulk));
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.err.println(e.getErrorMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

Source: http://codeflex.co/delete-objects-from-amazon-s3-bucket-using-aws-sdk-for-java/

Answer (score 0):

### kotlin

```
class S3(
    var bucketName: String? = null,
    var key: String? = null,
    val accessKey: String? = null,
    val secretKey: String? = null,
    val region: String? = null
)

fun delete(
    s3: S3,
    keyword: String = "",
) {
    with(s3) {
        val client = client(accessKey, secretKey, region)

        var objects = client.listObjects(bucketName, key)
        while (true) {
            for (i in objects.objectSummaries) {
                if (!i.key.contains(keyword)) {
                    continue
                }
                client.deleteObject(bucketName, i.key)
            }

            if (objects.isTruncated) {
                objects = client.listNextBatchOfObjects(objects)
            } else {
                break
            }
        }

        var versions = client.listVersions(bucketName, key)
        while (true) {
            for (i in versions.versionSummaries) {
                if (!i.key.contains(keyword)) {
                    continue
                }
                client.deleteVersion(bucketName, i.key, i.versionId)
            }

            if (versions.isTruncated) {
                versions = client.listNextBatchOfVersions(versions)
            } else {
                break
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's my answer which worked for me, I used the answer from Danger

This takes time but eventually it deletes all the files and folder.

```
public static void deleteObjects(AmazonS3 s3Client, String bucketName, String folderPath)
    {
    while(getFilesListInBucket(s3Client, bucketName, folderPath).size()>0) {
        for (S3ObjectSummary file : s3Client.listObjects(bucketName, folderPath).getObjectSummaries()) {
            s3Client.deleteObject(bucketName, file.getKey());
        }
    }
}
```