# how to get file list inside of a folder in Amazon S3 Bucket

Tags: ios, objective-c, amazon-s3, directory

Ok, I see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9329234/amazon-aws-ios-sdk-how-to-list-all-file-names-in-a-folder) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15022707/how-to-use-aws-ios-sdk-to-delete-a-folder-and-all-its-objects-in-side-bucket) and [documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/ListingKeysHierarchy.html) telling amazon is flat file system and for to create/get/set folders , one has to use Delimiter='/' and Prefix.

But I didnt get it, I mean I couldnt write the code. So I have a bucket and a folder  with some files,I want list of those files

So I tried `bucket/folder` , `/bucket/folder/` ,  `bucket/folder/` all of this fails.

If I try only `bucket`, it works fine

```
S3ListObjectsRequest *getListObjectsRequest= [[S3ListObjectsRequest alloc] initWithName:@"bucket"]; // tried also here bucket/folder , /bucket/folder/ ,  bucket/folder/ 
    S3ListObjectsResponse *getListObjectsResponse = [self.s3 listObjects:getListObjectsRequest];

    //test to see inside of the folder
    NSArray *objectsinamazon = [self.s3 listObjectsInBucket:@"bucket"]; //as I said I tried bucket/folder , /bucket/folder/ ,  bucket/folder/ all od this fails.

    NSLog(@"array is %@",objectsinamazon);

    S3ListObjectsResult *listObjectsResults = getListObjectsResponse.listObjectsResult;



    for (S3ObjectSummary *objectSummary in listObjectsResults.objectSummaries) {

        NSLog(@"Bucket Contents %@:",[objectSummary key]);
       //get last modified date of file by using meta data
    S3GetObjectMetadataRequest *getMetadataRequest = [[S3GetObjectMetadataRequest alloc] initWithKey:[objectSummary key] withBucket:@"bucket"];
    S3GetObjectMetadataResponse *getMetadataResponse = [self.s3 getObjectMetadata:getMetadataRequest];

}
}
```

I am asking exact syntax(code) to send `bucket/folder` request to amazon s3

Comment: Hi @MordFustang here is [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38454387/how-to-list-the-folders-at-a-specific-path-from-an-amazon-s3-bucket-in-objectiv/38454388#38454388) to this question, hope it helps.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

S3 is not flat, it just has only two levels: the bucket and the object name (it is flat **inside** the bucket).  The bucket is always just the bucket.  You're trying to add on to your bucket name, which produces an invalid bucket name.

The prefix and delimiter parameters are [properties on S3ListObjectsRequest](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSiOSSDK/latest/Classes/S3ListObjectsRequest.html#properties).  My Objective-C is rusty, but I think you can set those properties with:

```
getListObjectsRequest.prefix = @"my/prefix/";
getListObjectsRequest.delimiter = @"/";
```

before you submit the request to S3.